# Website Notification message

Tags: javascript, notifications

I am currently building a website (using only javascript for the moment) and I am looking for advise. I have been doing some research online but I could not find the best way and technology to be able to see real time the list of all people connected to my website.

I also would like to be able to send to one of them a notification (always the same) by clicking on their name.

I would like to have a message displayed on the person selected in real time that disappears after a certain amount of time

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is all about the server support, if its IIS then without a doubt SignalR is built for exactly this senario http://signalr.net/
Otherwise you are going to have to find a framework or role your own that fits your platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. For the moment I have not chose any webhost so that is why I am open to any suggestion.

I am trying to look for a simple solution to implement as well as a webhost that can offer the technology to support it

Comment: windows has the cost issue, but SignalR can do exactly what you are asking and there are plenty of demos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of programming language you use besides JavaScript, but I know there is something for .NET called SignalR: http://signalr.net/

For other programming languages, see: http://webandphp.com/BuildingRealtimeWebAppswithPHP-166928